# Get List of AWS S3 Directory Name from .net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, .net-core

I am just stuck with aws s3 on my .net core mvc application. I just simply need to input bucket name of s3 then return all of directory name list in this bucket but this simple task i didn't found anywhere on internet. I already tried few solution provided by AWS forum but problem is this absolutely not works at all. Bellow i have provided my controller code also forum link. Actually the issue they told is `Amazon.S3.IO` and `S3DirectoryInfo` namespace was removed from .net core so i am failed to follow them as they advised there. Any one can fix my code bellow which will give a list of bucket directory in .net core application?

I am using two nuget package-

`AWSSDK.Core` and `AWSSDK.S3`

[Forum Link - Amazon.S3.IO not supported in .Net Core anymore?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=245007)

**Controller:**

```cs
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;


public IActionResult Media()
{
    string bucketName = "domain33.com";
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("Access_Key_ID", "Secret_Access_Key", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

    var getResponse = s3Client.ListBucketsAsync(new GetObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName
    });


    var x = getResponse;

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `ListObjectsV2Async` method on `IAmazonS3` to retrieve a list of all of the existing objects in the bucket based on the [AWS's example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html). Their code is below in case the link dies:

```
// Copyright 2018 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0 (For details, see https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-developer-guide/blob/master/LICENSE-SAMPLECODE.)

﻿using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
{
    class ListObjectsTest
    {
        private const string bucketName = "*** bucket name ***";
        // Specify your bucket region (an example region is shown).
        private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USWest2;

        private static IAmazonS3 client;

        public static void Main()
        {
            client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
            ListingObjectsAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task ListingObjectsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    MaxKeys = 10
                };
                ListObjectsV2Response response;
                do
                {
                    response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

                    // Process the response.
                    foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("key = {0} size = {1}",
                            entry.Key, entry.Size);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Next Continuation Token: {0}", response.NextContinuationToken);
                    request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
                } while (response.IsTruncated);
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("S3 error occurred. Exception: " + amazonS3Exception.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on that sample, you could do further processing or add the keys to a list of strings for subsequent processing, instead of just writing it the console as their example code does. For instance, you could add each key to a list, and then process that list to calculate the distinct "directories".

Comment: Thing is that they call the word `directory` is `key`. Thats why i coudnt found this example over internet.

Comment: Ah - yeah, vernacular is the devil. S3 != a file system exactly, but generally, key means file path, whereas S3 doesn't really have a first class "folder" or "directory" concept, since an empty "folder" cannot exist in S3. I assumed you were looking to find unique "folders" in S3.